# Can my laptop display and external monitor have different aspect ratios while both are in use?

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display, aspect-ratio

Operating System: Windows 10

Laptop Aspect Ratio: 3:2

External Monitor Aspect Ratio: 16:9

Consider a mirrored display option: Will the image on the laptop display automatically be "adjusted" when it is shown on the external monitor of different aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Yes they can.

More nuanced:

You can set independant resolutions for the external display(s) and the internal display. Those do not all have to have the same ratio. E.g. 1024x768 (4:3) on a laptops internal screen and 2560x1440 (wide) on an external screen.

You can also mirror on screen so that you see the same thing on both displays. In that case the resolution (and the ratio) will be the same.